# How to print a table of numbers using angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am beginner of angularJs.
I want to print a number table according to the value inserted into text-box.
here is my code

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-app="" ng-controller="number1">
            Number: <input type="text" ng-model="num1"><br>
            <br>

                <p>{{num1}}</p>

        </div>

        <script>
            function number1($scope) {
            for(var i; i<=10;i++){
                $scope.num1 = 1*i
                        }

            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does work? What doesn't? What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       <div ng-app="" ng-controller="number1">
                Number: <input type="text" ng-model="num1"><br>
                <br>
                <div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]">
                    <p>{{num1}}*{{n}}={{num1 * n}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <script>
                function number1($scope) {
                    $scope.num1 = "1",
                }
            </script>
```

---

#### or

---

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="number1">
            Number: <input type="text" ng-model="num1"><br>
            <br>
            <div ng-repeat="n in numbers">
                <p>{{num1}}*{{n}}={{num1 * n}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function number1($scope) {
                $scope.num1 = "1",
                $scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterate over every number in array and render result of multiplication `{{num1 * i}}`.

For example it could look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="num1" />

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td ng-repeat="i in numbers">{{i}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{num1}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="i in numbers">{{i*num1}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where `numbers` is declared in controller:

```
$scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Here is a little demo to experiment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TXKzszn2t6sHHkPNNkqk?p=info